# Mysql migration error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I'm recieveing the following error when trying to migrate my database.

```
 Mysql2::Error: BLOB/TEXT column 'overview' can't have a default value: ALTER TABLE `habitat_versions` CHANGE `description` `overview` text DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
```

Can anyone tell me what command to type in order to resolve this?

Full code of the migration is below:

```
==  SplitHabitatDescriptionIntoIntroAndOverview: migrating ====================
-- rename_column(:habitat_versions, :description, :overview)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: BLOB/TEXT column 'overview' can't have a default value: ALTER TABLE `habitat_versions` CHANGE `description` `overview` text DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `query'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `block in execute'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `execute'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:211:in `execute'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:484:in `rename_column'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `say_with_time'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:458:in `method_missing'
/Users/webteam/wwf/db/migrate/20120523150123_split_habitat_description_into_intro_and_overview.rb:3:in `up'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block in migrate'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:129:in `with_connection'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:389:in `migrate'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `migrate'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:777:in `call'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:777:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in `block in migrate'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `each'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `migrate'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:193:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/webteam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: As the error says, remove the `default` from your migration as `blob` and `text` columns cannot have default values in MySQL.

Comment: so how exactly would i type that command?

Comment: Please post your migration in the question.

Comment: ok i have updated the question with the code

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in my comment above, `blob` and `text` column cannot have default values.  Please see "[The BLOB and TEXT Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html)"

You need to change your migration like follows:

```
change_table :habitat_version do |t|
  t.change :description, :overview, :text
end
```

Update: Please note that this migration changes column types of `description` and `overview` to `text`.

Comment: hmm, i pasted that in and it didnt work, said command not found

Comment: You don't paste this in the terminal/command prompt, you change your migration file which is in `db/migrate` directory.  The file name should end in `split_habitat_description_into_intro_and_overview.rb`

Comment: Oh ok, can you tell I'm new at this? I went to that file and pasted in what you sent. I re ran the migration and now I'm getting this error message:   Mysql2::Error: Table 'wwf_development.habitat_version' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `habitat_version`

Comment: @user1836025, based on your migration class name it appears that you are not trying to change existing column.  You have one column which you'd like to split into two.  In that case I suggest you add the two columns first, migrate the data and drop the old column.